# The project has static values ​but don't work FormatException: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)

Tags: c#, exception, guid, string-parsing

I have a core project that stores static data, I use it in the data preoctc and I get this error
System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'ERP.Core.Constants.CoreDefaultValues' threw an exception.'

Code Data

```
   builder.HasData(new CashFlowItem
        {
            Id = CoreDefaultValues.DefaultExpenseCashFlowItemId,
            Name = "Income",
            Description = "Income",
            BelongTo = BelongTo.OperatingActivity,
            ReferenceType = ReferenceType.CatalogCashFlowItem
        }, new CashFlowItem
        {
            Id = CoreDefaultValues.DefaultExpenseCashFlowItemId,
            Name = "Expense",
            Description = "Expense",
            BelongTo = BelongTo.OperatingActivity,
            ReferenceType = ReferenceType.CatalogCashFlowItem
        });
```

Code Core class CoreDefaultValues

```
public static class CoreDefaultValues{
  public static Guid DefaultIncomeCashFlowItemId = new("a0ce69fc-dac3-4d05-8084-82edb1478be6");
    public static Guid DefaultExpenseCashFlowItemId  = new("CA32B849-C4FA-476D-AC29-D6EFE2848F74");
}
```

I tried changing formats

new Guid(CoreDefaultValues.DefaultExpenseCashFlowItemId.ToString(("D"))),
but nothing helped
all exeption
[image]

add all field in class

```
public static class CoreDefaultValues
{
    public  const string AdminRoleName = "Admin";
    public  const string Version = "1.0";
    public  static System.Guid ApplicationUserId = new System.Guid("0F235EA1-D3A8-4894-94A0-7E7A3081EC12");
    public  static System.Guid AccountId = new System.Guid("0F235EA1-D4A8-4894-94A0-7E7A3081EC12");
    public  static System.Guid DefaultProductId1 = new System.Guid("77E46C72-B10E-4F3E-AAB2-9079F197698C");
    public  static System.Guid DefaultProductId2 = new System.Guid("049BE269-1A0A-4F70-BB46-482782808378");
    public  static System.Guid DefaultWarehouseId1 = new System.Guid("049BE269-1A0A-4F70-BB46-482782804378");
    public  static System.Guid DefaultCustomerInvoice = new System.Guid("049BE269-1A3A-4F70-BB46-482782804378");
    public  static System.Guid DefaultIncomingBankPayment = new System.Guid("046BE269-1A3A-4F70-BB46-482782804378");
    public  static System.Guid WorkScheduleId = new System.Guid("da6a28fc-b7bc-4cda-ba63-c236daaca8ee");
    public static System.Guid CompanyId2 = new("cd0cc42f-ea18-4538-893b-0f90001d48c1");
    public static System.Guid CustomerId2 = new("90609e9f-8aa6-4528-b5f2-73dae301ec5c");
    public static System.Guid VendorId2 = new("6e8b2202-0060-4366-ba79-fe5ec0b33a11");
    public static System.Guid ContractId1 = new("24b3f4a6-9c94-4d67-a9f8-9ca50284ce3b");
    public static System.Guid ContractId2 = new("80267ab7-244a-4ad5-91e6-2e2a6831968f");
    public static System.Guid WarehouseId2 = new("2c89b195-e04e-4945-a4d4-d9a1f20fa1cc");
    public static System.Guid CashId = new("55f9e845-910b-4294-a77d-b487ff314076");
    public static System.Guid BaseDocumentId = new("ad34d649-5b1c-4c05-9841-7498aaae7ae5");
    public static System.Guid IncomeItemId = new("8811ac5b-ae3e-4928-ad15-6a03ac927099");
    public static System.Guid ProductId1 = new("77E46C72-B10E-4F3E-AAB2-9079F197698C");
    public static System.Guid ProductId2 = new("049BE269-1A0A-4F70-BB46-482782808378");
    public  static System.Guid DivisionId = new System.Guid("046BE859-1A3A-4F70-BB46-482782804378");

    public  static System.Guid CompanyId1 = new System.Guid("56E46C72-B10E-4F3E-AAB2-9079F197698C");
    public  static System.Guid EmployeeId = new System.Guid("b26831a2-67c5-46dd-8e2d-3181ba06f84a");
    public  static System.Guid BankAccountId = new System.Guid("b29561a2-67c5-46dd-8e2d-3181ba06f84a");
    public  static System.Guid BankAcquirerId = new System.Guid("b36561a2-67c5-46dd-8e2d-3181ba06f84a");
    public  static System.Guid CashRegisterId = new System.Guid("b36561a2-67c5-43dd-8e2d-3181ba06f84a");
    public  static System.Guid VendorInvoiceId = new System.Guid("b36561a2-67c5-49ad-8e2d-3181ba06f84a");
    public  static System.Guid VendorId = new System.Guid("b36561a2-62c5-49ad-8e2d-3181ba06f84a");
    public  static System.Guid BankId = new System.Guid("0b7167ab-9615-41d8-a2f0-c2f446d1c158");

    public  static System.Guid CustomerId = new System.Guid("b36561a2-62c5-49ad-8e2d-3156ba06f84a");
    public  static System.Guid AssemblyDisassemblyOrderId1 = new System.Guid("8607ec1c-f053-45ac-8e34-e44a2326d931");
    public  static System.Guid DefaultIncomeItemId  = new System.Guid("d1b1b1b1-2112-40cf-b160-9b54e2a2f172");
    public  static System.Guid DefaultExpenseItemId  = new System.Guid("e2c2c2c2-2112-40cf-b160-9b54e2a2f172");
    public  static System.Guid DefaultCurrencyId  = new System.Guid("897e9ed2-485f-11e8-965c-5404a6690035");
    public  static System.Guid DefaultIncomeCashFlowItemId = new System.Guid("a0ce69fc-dac3-4d05-8084-82edb1478be6");
    public  static System.Guid DefaultExpenseCashFlowItemId  = new System.Guid("ca32b849-c4fa-476d-ac29-d6efe2848f74");
    public  static System.Guid AnalyticsTypeOfIncomeExpenseItemId  = new System.Guid("584688b4-728b-4c50-a3a1-f6e3ee54c5ba");
    public  static System.Guid AnalyticsTypeOfIncomeExpenseItemId1  = new System.Guid("484688b4-728b-4c50-a3a1-f6e3ee54c5ba");
    public  static System.Guid ApplicationRoleId  = new System.Guid("d33c7d92-5ac0-4375-a050-6aaf48a65574");
    public  static System.Guid ApplicationUserId1  = new System.Guid("b0c720e5-6905-4845-9722-92bfd75436fa");
    public  static System.Guid ApplicationUserSettingsId  = new System.Guid("3a4b3507-9adc-4905-881a-52221471ca76");
    public  static System.Guid ArApOffsetId  = new System.Guid("d52688c4-0d25-428c-b356-069f55ca3089");
    public  static System.Guid ArApOffsetId1  = new System.Guid("fec54b03-b649-4d8c-b520-382503416f89");
    public  static System.Guid DivisionId1  = new System.Guid("fec54b03-b649-4d8c-b520-382403216f99");
    public  static System.Guid ApplicationUserId2  = new System.Guid("b87bfc24-2ce5-4511-b4f2-a223c1ff1371");
    public  static System.Guid ApplicationUserId3  = new System.Guid("d583cc23-20c5-4889-84bf-7ed6b6498000");
    public  static System.Guid ArApOffset2  = new System.Guid(" 77fadadb-6c6b-4997-a90c-6e42f285ab8b");
    public  static System.Guid ArApWriteOff2  = new System.Guid ("9b37cd3f-aef8-4b16-ba7a-9a2516d48a68");
    public  static System.Guid AssemblyDisassemblyOfGood1  = new System.Guid ("197d7dfc-c0fd-4e2e-8644-4c535ff239d8");
    public  static System.Guid UnitId  = new System.Guid ("e0368b36-7699-4e01-8cb3-31433b5a1ab4");
    public  static System.Guid AssemblyDisassemblyOfGoodGood1  = new System.Guid(" 8b56af46-f96c-4eef-b9a6-11eb25e5694d");
    public  static System.Guid AssemblyDisassemblyOfGoodGood2  = new System.Guid(" 9b56af46-f96c-4eef-b9a6-11eb25e5694d");
    public  static System.Guid AssemblyDisassemblyOfGoodId  = new System.Guid("fdb21ee1-379a-4e83-83a8-f962da4ef614");
    public  static System.Guid AssemblyDisassemblyOrderGoodId  = new System.Guid("4bced959-03b8-4ce9-8ce0-522a39807952");
    public  static System.Guid DefaultWarehouseId2  = new System.Guid ("8a5cf88f-4aa0-4cc1-b5ad-9abe0018d4a0");
    public  static System.Guid BaseDocumentAtId  = new System.Guid("a053e58a-f41d-444f-a357-4b8b119d1960");
    public  static System.Guid VendorCustomerId  = new System.Guid("44b67059-584c-4370-9a60-c16d2c026aaa");
    public  static System.Guid BankAccountVendorCustomerId  = new System.Guid ("7b43e128-5f6e-4487-937b-5c78eff598df");
    public  static System.Guid BillOfMaterialId  = new System.Guid ("ed0bab1f-98ae-4576-8124-9f5b17f8a0ba");
    public  static System.Guid CalendarDayId  = new System.Guid ("d3c0d2c1-fbf8-418a-b3f7-e2d872aacc36");
    public  static System.Guid CalendarDayId1  = new System.Guid("d2c0d2c1-fbf8-418a-b3f7-e2d872aacc36");
    public  static System.Guid CashFlowItemId  = new System.Guid("ecd168e9-03fb-448b-afb5-da5413d4a805");
    public  static System.Guid AnalyticsTypeOfActivePassiveItemId  = new System.Guid("4d5b36c9-22e0-4326-bfba-c50d412edc8a");
    public  static System.Guid CategoryOfFixedAssetsId  = new System.Guid("dbbb277a-8a0e-4f35-8902-48e497d004df");
    public  static System.Guid TaxGroupId  = new System.Guid("dd99aa4b-c4c6-493d-acbb-b647f7c71178");
    public  static System.Guid AccountId1  = new System.Guid ("333eeb4f-1f7f-4047-946c-1daa0c28aa4b");
    public  static System.Guid ActivePassiveItemId  = new System.Guid ("bd262138-aa26-4629-885a-840b28910870");
    public  static System.Guid CommodityWaybillId  = new System.Guid("69c6d419-6d29-4124-aeb9-965cda71fa20");
    public  static System.Guid CommodityWaybillInformationId  = new System.Guid("bf69ba90-2b7c-449b-b902-7b0f9b60c72d");
    public  static System.Guid CommodityWaybillProductId  = new System.Guid("5f3497b0-ee9c-4a5b-ac86-4434696185df");
    public  static System.Guid CompanyCashBoxId  = new System.Guid("b6fff3ae-01d 1-47cb-b789-8f 3878c9552f");
    public  static System.Guid ConsumptionOrderId  = new System.Guid("b54f4079-2f76-4a00-a810-d757c7baecf8");
    public  static System.Guid ProductId  = new System.Guid ("5d84c5fe-de19-469a-acd7-52a6525bdfda");
    public  static System.Guid ConsumptionOrderGoodId  = new System.Guid("de5b29b0-6d 63-44e3-abd4-c2a2ec8c8f6d");
    public  static System.Guid CountryId  = new System.Guid("f689dcb0-40ba-4451-ba91-03f5e41ab767");
    public  static System.Guid DeductionId  = new System.Guid("11458640-e97b-4531-b355-ac13a863323c");
    public  static System.Guid DeliveryMethodId  = new System.Guid("e696d028-b5cb-4c84-9a71-0b99966e222f");
    public  static System.Guid DepreciationChargeId  = new System.Guid("dc917185-1bff-42b9-9b33-548b63d23c08");
    public  static System.Guid DistributionOfLandedCostId  = new System.Guid("5c8cbe1d-bd2e-4760-84c5-16b2e0660214");
    public  static System.Guid DistributionOfLandedCostDocumentVendorInvoiceId  =
        new System.Guid("f03fcec1-f857-4931-892f-045c77e3cf95");
    public  static System.Guid DistributionOfLandedCostExpenseId  = new System.Guid("0ab16ddb-dfa9-46da-863f-68f07bab2459");
    public  static System.Guid DistributionOfLandedCostGoodId  = new System.Guid("6716b004-fdec-4031-8a11-7227a8d49ea9");
    public  static System.Guid CompanyId  = new System.Guid ("0a30637e-6156-4c85-8e38-86c8ffdb30a3");
    public  static System.Guid VehicleId  = new System.Guid("454d39ec-1f4c-4ecb-913a-6d6ac389111e");
    public  static System.Guid DriverId  = new System.Guid ("d0753a9a-d6c8-454e-829b-171e4d539d31");
    public  static System.Guid EmployeeDismissalId  = new System.Guid ("c5625b8a-9a4b-4a31-8d96-38949621eed6");
    public  static System.Guid PersonId  = new System.Guid("0448b082-52db-486e-9b61-aecf3bc79d84");
    public  static System.Guid PositionId  = new System.Guid("8e14b054-f36f-4f94-8d73-615a41a61d92");
    public  static System.Guid EmployeeHireId  = new System.Guid("cda494ed-f914-4548-8d14-dc19cfdda3f2");
    public  static System.Guid HeadEmployeeId  = new System.Guid(" 7092684d-b164-43ba-9775-bc0320b96761");
    public  static System.Guid AuthorId  = new System.Guid ("f85e248f-f5f9-47ed-9eea-ce46094f4aa9");
    public  static System.Guid CreatedUserId  = new System.Guid("c1cb55a2-8119-42a4-a667-2417294a8370");
    public  static System.Guid EmployeeTransferId  = new System.Guid("1ee42b5b-e4a1-484e-b77b-7e4bb0729c05");
    public  static System.Guid EnterOfSettlementsBalanceId  = new System.Guid("8ea72f4a-5c7c-4de5-aece-ee1c6cbee0e7");
    public  static System.Guid EnterOfSettlementsBalanceGoodId  = new System.Guid("3e957f6f-f5c1-476d-9f3d-c946bb0c7573");
    public  static System.Guid CurrencyId  = new System.Guid("3e957d6f-f5c1-476d-1f4d-c946bb0c7573");
    public  static System.Guid ExchangeDifferenceCalculationId  = new System.Guid("93b76a86-ddf8-4e68-8295-0eb4ed086713");
    public  static System.Guid AnalyticsTypeOfIncomeId  = new System.Guid("43ea078b-606d-4b30-8128-41cecb87a046");
    public  static System.Guid ExpenseItemId  = new System.Guid("906c067e-b0a1-403e-9302-b31d03cf1b8f");
    public  static System.Guid FeatureId  = new System.Guid("a526e9f1-6724-4562-82e6-adb9b758d4f0");
    public  static System.Guid FixedAssetId  = new System.Guid("b43a6f3e-6394-4527-83ad-5e331792ae40");
    public  static System.Guid FixedAssetInitialRecognitionId  = new System.Guid("95a1b41d-7bfb-4174-89a0-84554ced2b85");
    public  static System.Guid FixedAssetInitialRecognitionGoodId  = new System.Guid("04007529-9a82-4bdf-911b-846f5005465d");
    public  static System.Guid FixedAssetTransactionHistoryId  = new System.Guid("fc1852df-d711-4720-94c7-739d8ed80109");
    public  static System.Guid GoodsRegradingId  = new System.Guid("a4d0e61a-702a-4fcf-9fce-5a9f76aaba9f");
    public  static System.Guid GoodsRegradingGoodPostingId  = new System.Guid("4cfd26ea-3a88-4497-9f52-0d8378ecc876");
    public  static System.Guid GoodsRegradingGoodUnpostingId  = new System.Guid("9738668a-977f-4216-a226-6d9127c9e73e");
    public  static System.Guid GoodsTransferOrderId  = new System.Guid("7669fc3c-c36d-45ec-b252-ced531fd5ef6");
    public  static System.Guid GoodsTransferOrderGoodId  = new System.Guid("fc0cc7d1-4b55-41a0-b2a2-77cebbce14cd");
    public  static System.Guid ImportId  = new System.Guid("997cb61c-0b1b-4e7b-9d10-1dbc3cb2ba32");
    public  static System.Guid ImportAdditionalDocumentId  = new System.Guid("33c9f32b-f193-4b50-bf3c-b8f2f7ccff72");
    public  static System.Guid AccountAnalyticId  = new System.Guid("2c7a5685-0b9f-49a6-9189-3c47acb6c59b");
    public  static System.Guid ImportCustomsCostId  = new System.Guid("7744e1ac-75b5-4b1e-9062-9026ea8ffc0d");
    public  static System.Guid ImportExciseDutyId  = new System.Guid("7731d59f-d0fa-477f-b044-74d50c0ce884");
    public  static System.Guid ImportImportTaxId  = new System.Guid("86654949-a56e-4cb1-ab23-4a96e5de64ac");
    public  static System.Guid? ContractId  = new System.Guid("2a772c6e-bbd2-46df-981b-c4a84f8a0bd5");
    public  static System.Guid ImportVatId  = new System.Guid("97e77f38-daf4-425e-9807-61a23e3d71cf");
    public  static System.Guid MaterialAndWorkId  = new System.Guid("f90af516-4e21-4638-acf9-6792816207b5");
    public  static System.Guid PriceTypeId  = new System.Guid("ede7fe26-1b48-418e-9ea8-92b7e259f51f");
    public  static System.Guid ProductBatchId  = new System.Guid("9ed5de81-9b46-47d3-b8ac-b6b752c2ff75");
    public  static System.Guid ProductionId  = new System.Guid("2a6bbf9a-0a00-492a-97e2-b07e08dc5cf1");
    public  static System.Guid VariantId  = new System.Guid("d8eb3e17-0844-4ece-9a76-daa5f192faf6");
    public  static System.Guid ProductionManufacturedProductId  = new System.Guid("d8b4f162-600c-4239-a1a1-120b5b97463e");
    public  static System.Guid ProductionMaterialAndWorkId  = new System.Guid("74d27375-6630-42fd-8cb4-67ca634225a1");
    public  static System.Guid ProductPricingId  = new System.Guid("989083d4-5b99-479f-9cdf-14f9862330df");
    public  static System.Guid ProductPricingGoodId  = new System.Guid("ceda7af9-1faa-4fe0-806a-6aa3c77097e2");
    public  static System.Guid PurchaseOrderId  = new System.Guid("a74c15ac-965a-4364-aff5-51f9cd8d74d4");
    public  static System.Guid AccountingManualTransactionId  = new System.Guid("32cbf1bb-083b-4eb3-ab4f-b534f1d193f6");
    public  static System.Guid PurchaseOrderGoodId  = new System.Guid("4a8a78ba-7e75-49d5-809f-326d75caf818");
    public  static System.Guid PurchaseOrderPaymentOffsetId  = new System.Guid("9725fd34-ae2e-420f-88ca-179703b6fd21");

    public  static System.Guid AccountingManualTransactionTransactionId  =
        new System.Guid("6a0380db-e166-4ad2-a411-007ba8d3cb35");

    public  static System.Guid ReturnOfGoodsFromCustomerId  = new System.Guid("e31d9e1d-5a1b-4fff-9f51-a9ca6ce8239d");
    public  static System.Guid ReturnOfGoodsFromCustomerGoodId  = new System.Guid("700f9e93-3897-4e6f-809e-dd5c7eb2341e");
    public  static System.Guid AcquiringOperationId  = new System.Guid("83ce9cd1-7b0f-4178-949d-6b25154555f0");
    public  static System.Guid AccrualId  = new System.Guid("a7eb53a3-5e38-447f-9813-c1de87492c9b");
    public  static System.Guid ReturnOfGoodsFromVendorId  = new System.Guid("57b54627-7c6d-40a2-a9f8-578ba1e3887f");
    public  static System.Guid ReturnOfGoodsFromVendorGoodId  = new System.Guid("6d39c320-5993-4125-a3e2-0e7405ff66fa");
    public  static System.Guid SalaryAccrualId  = new System.Guid("817e10fd-9d0b-443d-82fd-183a2b308d7f");
    public  static System.Guid SalaryAccrualPersonId  = new System.Guid("265db6e3-8567-42dd-91b8-7571ad20a1ab");
    public  static System.Guid SalesOrderId  = new System.Guid("4de4397f-ac2f-4362-b23e-fd0ce4960431");
    public  static System.Guid SalesOrderPaymentOffsetId  = new System.Guid("97b11e9a-9b35-4017-bec0-752d9890fa8d");
    public  static System.Guid SpecificationId  = new System.Guid("fc6f37cd-b5dd-416a-a8b6-e64143a8444a");
    public  static System.Guid SpecificationIncludedProductId  = new System.Guid("75bd8d57-56b7-4eff-b506-4d962d8742d6");
    public  static System.Guid StocktakingId  = new System.Guid("5479ab3c-a4ad-411d-ac7c-d74140d75f90");
    public  static System.Guid StocktakingGoodId  = new System.Guid("6122b784-4b38-44a7-b79d-7abbeb8fb381");
    public  static System.Guid TransferOfGoodId  = new System.Guid("51776472-2afd-419e-bfec-eb6b2c35c0a9");
    public  static System.Guid WithholdingTaxRateId  = new System.Guid("bb658d3e-9123-49bc-bd99-93af16b42e0e");
    public  static System.Guid TransferOfGoodGoodId  = new System.Guid("4a53f63b-6b41-482f-bdd7-9fe01d91af66");
    public  static System.Guid VatArticleId  = new System.Guid("95cbac8e-b02e-4b9a-aad1-33c14b639b55");
    public  static System.Guid VendorInvoicePaymentOffsetId  = new System.Guid("2c00b2f3-7b7c-4601-a823-b2a041cb388f");
    public  static System.Guid VendorInvoiceServicesAndAssetGoodId  = new System.Guid("e833d5fd-848c-497e-9ae0-7a5bbbbc0fe9");
    public  static System.Guid VendorInvoiceServicesAndAssetId  = new System.Guid("719ea7eb-95e7-4d55-8da9-06dbea1d70fa");
    public  static System.Guid VendorInvoiceServicesAndAssetsPaymentOffsetId  =
        new System.Guid("1fc8ea71-dd68-4552-86fa-d20912f8e2bd");

    public  static System.Guid VendorItemId  = new System.Guid("20223d7d-761b-469b-8cec-3e6cab601790");
    public  static System.Guid WriteOffGoodId  = new System.Guid("e754796b-60f0-413e-82ee-cf355d6f8b8f");
    public  static System.Guid WriteOffGoodGoodId  = new System.Guid("d9c548b5-a8a6-45c2-bbe2-30f79ae6f590");
    public  static System.Guid IncomeCashFlowItemId  = new System.Guid("c9c548b5-a8a6-45c2-bbe2-30f79ae6f590");

    //Seed Old
    public static Guid CurrencyUSD = new("9ca042d1-4d46-11e8-80c4-000c29a07c37");
    public static Guid CurrencyEUR = new("d76b5989-8904-11e8-80c7-000c29a07c37");
    public static Guid CurrencyGBP = new("6447f8a9-f6d5-11e8-843d-000c29b16d56");
    public static Guid CurrencyCHF = new("d28f037b-9d6f-11e8-80da-000c29a07c37");
    public static Guid CurrencyRUB = new("e6c1743c-8904-11e8-80c7-000c29a07c37");
    public static Guid CurrencyGEL = new("e2c1743c-8904-11e8-80c7-000c29a07c37");

    public static Guid AdminRoleId = new("ED667DBD-ADEE-42B4-9499-82980F333690");
    public static Guid UserRoleId = new("C0AECF48-8EFB-4887-AF3F-BC6A56910BE4");

    public static Guid AdminUserId = new("0F235EA1-D3A8-4894-94A0-7E7A3081EC12");
}
```

Comment: Post the actual *full* exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`. `new Guid("a0ce69fc-dac3-4d05-8084-82edb1478be6");` works just fine. So does `new("CA32B849-C4FA-476D-AC29-D6EFE2848F74");`. The error is raised somewhere else

Comment: The strings look like they were copy/pasted, that's wise.  But you might have copied more than the eyes can see, a Unicode symbol with an invisible glyph such as left-to-right mark or zero-width space.  A hex viewer can reveal them.

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about

Comment: Perhaps one thing to try is to carefully retype these two lines by hand (i.e. not using copy and paste) and see if that solves your problem. Also, please confirm that `Guid` is `System.Guid` and there are no other static GUIDs in this file: if it actually contains 10 GUIDs but you've only shown two, then it's likely the error is with a GUID you haven't shown. Also, if you want more information on exactly which GUID is failing to parse, put all of your `new Guid(...)` calls into a unit test, run that and see where the exception gets raised.

Comment: I have added all the values ​​so that you can familiarize yourself with them

Comment: No repro with the original 2 GUIDs. One of the *other* GUIDs is invalid. Instead of creating all those GUIDs as static fields try creating them in a method to see which one fails to parse.

Comment: What you posted isn't the exception. It's a screenshot of some of the exception fields that can't be used. Either log and post the actual full exception or click on the `Copy Details` link on the exception popup

Comment: I went through the debugger to initialize the fields, those fields that fell, I changed the Guid for them and everything worked, here are the fields that I changed, why exactly they fell, I don’t know

Before
  public  static System.Guid CalendarDayId1  = new System.Guid("2d1fcf99-8be6-4d5d-a15b-af398dcba9c2");
After
  public  static System.Guid CalendarDayId1  = new System.Guid("d2c0d2c1-fbf8-418a-b3f7-e2d872aacc36");

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Two of the GUIDs are invalid. The actual full exception text shows the actual location of the error.

I put the static class in a separate file and tried to access one of the fields :

```
Console.WriteLine(CoreDefaultValues.ApplicationUserId);
```

The exception I got was :

```
Unhandled exception. System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CoreDefaultValues' threw an exception.
 ---> System.FormatException: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).
   at System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure(Boolean overflow, String failureMessageID)
   at System.Guid.TryParseExactD(ReadOnlySpan`1 guidString, GuidResult& result)
   at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(ReadOnlySpan`1 guidString, GuidResult& result)
   at System.Guid..ctor(String g)
   at CoreDefaultValues..cctor() in C:\Projects\Work\ARC\CoreDefaultValues.cs:line 76
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Projects\Work\ARC\Program.cs:line 1
```

This says there's a `FormatException` at line 76

```
CompanyCashBoxId  = new System.Guid("b6fff3ae-01d 1-47cb-b789-8f 3878c9552f");
```

That string contains spaces between the letters and can't be parsed as a GUID.

After fixing this the code fails at line 79, another invalid GUID `"de5b29b0-6d 63-44e3-abd4-c2a2ec8c8f6d"`